# Asana SQL API Asana2sql missing followers data

Tags: python, sqlite, asana

I am able to successfully create and synchronize to a sqlite db using asana2sql.py.  All the tables are populated, including the followers table.  However, the followers table has no data.

I haven't seen any issues in the code.  Has this happened to anyone else using the asana2sql api?  What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that didn't make it into the library initially.  There's a pull request to add it which should be resolved soon.  You can work off of that branch in the meantime.

https://github.com/Asana/asana2sql/pull/3